# Facebook chatbot with multiple keywords

Tags: bots, chatbot, messenger, facebook-chatbot

I have done a tutorial how to setup a Facebook chatbot for a fanpage.
It works perfect and we also can change the keyword and the message that pops up in case a user types exact the keyword.

Now the only thing is, we do not figure out, how to add multiple keywords with answers.

```html
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request')
var app = express()

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Index route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world, I am a chat bot')
})

// for Facebook verification
app.get('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === 'token') {
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge'])
    }
    res.send('Error, wrong token')
})

// Spin up the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('running on port', app.get('port'))
})


// API End Point - 

app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
    for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
        sender = event.sender.id
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            text = event.message.text
            if (text === 'hi') {
                sendGenericMessage(sender)
                continue
            }
            sendTextMessage(sender, "parrot: " + text.substring(0, 200))
        }
        if (event.postback) {
            text = JSON.stringify(event.postback)
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback received: "+text.substring(0, 200), token)
            continue
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

var token = " enter token here"

// function to echo back messages

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
    messageData = {
        text:text
    }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
        }
    })
}


// Send an test message back as two cards.

function sendGenericMessage(sender) {
    messageData = {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "generic",
                "elements": [{
                    "title": "title 1",
                    "subtitle": "subtitle",
                    "image_url": "url of image",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
                        "title": "Facebook"
                    }, {
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "https://www.reddit.com",
                        "title": "Reddit"
                    },{
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "https://twitter.com/",
                        "title": "Twitter"
                    }],
                }, {
                    "title": "Title 2 ",
                    "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                    "image_url": "imgurl",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    },{
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    }, {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    }],
                },  {
                    "title": "title",
                    "subtitle": "subtitle",
                    "image_url": "http://www.google.com",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    },{
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    }, {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": "title",
                        "payload": "payload",
                    }],
                }]  
            } 
        }
    }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say - You need to handle multiple keywords for same answer? If that is the case, then facebook sends the message as text on webhook. You need to catch it and send message back to facebook accordingly.

As in the code you've sent, [if (text === 'hi')], you need sample messages(hi in this case) to be stored in system and map the answer.